# Rebuilding my entire Fallout Shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I made some construction choices at the start of my Fallout Shelter that I'm now unhappy with. Can I send 25 (the maximum) dwellers out to the wasteland and rebuild my shelter and have them come back to repopulate it?

I have maxed out my cash so I could make an amazing vault now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: This is a bad idea**

---

If you want to rebuild from the vault door, the only way is to remove all your living quarters and you can only do that if you first evict (or kill) all your dwellers. Including exploring dwellers.

Then you can rebuild. But, and here's the important thing. More dwellers don't just appear like they did when you started.

In theory this situation can be remedied by getting rare dwellers from lunchboxes. But I've opened 3 lunchboxes and no one has appeared...

---

Edit: After 4 weeks of nothing, I finally got someone from a lunchboxes. They operated the radio room until another came and now I have breeding stock. Game saved!

Comment: I had a survival vault get wiped out down to three (related) people, and had a few new ones show up at the door to help repopulate. There might need to be living quarters for them to occupy before they start showing up.

Comment: @DCShannon Well, I've rebuilt and have a living quarters for them (as well as every other room) yet still no one comes

Comment: That sucks, man. Should ask a question about what conditions are needed for dwellers to show up at the door.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.  Dwellers in the wasteland still requires living spaces in your shelter.

If you need to change the room directly connected to your vault gate, you must kill/remove everyone to be able to delete it.

Dwellers waiting at the vault door needs to be saved up so you can immediately put in new dwellers.

Comment: If you have an elevator immediately after the vault door (highly recommended) then its much easier to destroy things and rebuild.

Comment: I've done as you've said, but more dwellers aren't appearing...

Comment: @Coomie More dwellers would have started appearing if you were completely out of dwellers, but if you still have 25 then the chances wouldn't be that high. It seems like random wasteland dwellers stop showing up at some point, but I'm not sure when.

Comment: @DCShannon Nope, it's been over a week with no dwellers turning up on my door. I currently have no one, not even exploring.

Comment: Darn it, it's been a long time since I did this.  I may have saved 10 dwellers at the entrance before I did this... sorry about messing it up...

Comment: it'll be due to the lack of anyone opperating the radio. Try again, but leave enough settlers to opperate your basic resource producers and the radio

Comment: then that's not removing all buildings and you will not be able to remove the default built land and elevator.  In order to go all the way up to the vault door, absolutely every thing has to be destroyed.

The trick is to save 10 dwellers outside the vault, and once you destroy the last building, rebuild and hire those waiting dwellers.

Answer (score 2):

As Nelson [said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272986/42679), just sending your dwellers out of the vault won't let you destroy all your rooms to rebuild.

What you can do, however, is rebuild step-by-step, or build some temporary accommodation out of the way somewhere (probably in a very deep level) then destroy all the other rooms and rebuild. I've done this a couple of times. If you're planning on moving your lift shafts around it can be a faff, but it's eminently possible.